# If the average of a positive sequence converges to zero, does the average of the square converge to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Give $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\rightarrow 0$, does it imply that $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}\rightarrow 0?$ if $x_i\geq 0$.

Thank you @D.B.  point out a counter example when $x_i = (-1)^i$. If we are given additional conditions $x_i\geq 0$, does the convergence hold?

Comment: It is known that $\liminf x_i=0$, so $\liminf x_i^2=0$,...well...hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether there is a sequence $(x_k)$ of nonnegative real numbers such that, as $n$ approaches infinity, 
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}$$
approaches zero, but
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2}{n}$$
does not approach zero.

The answer is "yes".$\;$Here is an example . . .

For each positive integer $k$, let
$$
x_k=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt[3]{k}&\text{if$\;k\;$is a perfect cube}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and for each positive integer $n$, let $c_n=\left\lfloor{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right\rfloor$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}
&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{c_n} c_k}{n}
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
&\le
\frac
{\sum_{k=1}^{c_n} c_k}
{c_n^3}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{c_n(c_n+1)}{2c_n^3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which approaches zero, as $n$ approaches infinity.
\begin{align*}
\text{But}\;\;\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2}{n}
&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{c_n} c_k^2}{n}\\[4pt]
&>
\frac
{\sum_{k=1}^{c_n} c_k^2}
{(c_n+1)^3}\\[4pt]
&\ge
\frac
{\sum_{k=1}^{c_n} c_k^2}
{8c_n^3}\\[4pt]
&=
\frac
{c_n(c_n+1)(2c_n+1)}
{48c_n^3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is bounded below by ${\large{\frac{1}{24}}}$, hence the $\text{LHS}$ does not approach zero, as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Great counterexample! Thank you very much!   I try square root and quad-root it turns out that only cube root could work.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Consider the sequence where the $x_i = (-1)^i$.  Then, the first sequence converges, but the second diverges.

Comment: how about given additional conditions: $x_i\geq 0 $

Comment: What if we stipulate that $\sum x_i$ must converge on its own as a series. Clearly your example does not.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Would you mind explaining a bit more concrete?

Comment: Well, yes, actually.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Why?

Answer (score -1):

If you want the series themselves to converge (without the division by $n$), this means the $x_i$ must eventually become smaller than $1$ and thus $x_j^2<x_j$ for all $j>N \in \mathbb{N}$. In that case your conjecture would hold true.

Comment: If all your $x_i$ are $\geq 0$ then: No. If for every $N$ there is an $x_j \geq 1$ with $j \geq N$ you could simply add up those $x_j$ (sub-sequence) and find the sum will diverge.

Comment: Its ok, that was the case I was considering in my comment by contraposition (if one can actually call it that). If the $x_j$ do not eventually become sufficiently small, there will be a sub-sequence that diverges.

Comment: Note that this fact is by far not sufficient for actual convergence of the sequence, it is only necessary.